# Server not listening on port 445

Tags: windows-server-2016, server-message-block

I have a Windows Server 2016 server that is not listening on port 445.

The *Server* service is running and the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters** registry entry is exactly the same as a server where port 445 is listening. This server was recently virtualized and ITSec enforced some of the settings as follows:
**HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Wintrust\Config\EnableCertPaddingCheck** set to 1
and **HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\RestrictAnonymous** set to 1

This is affecting users who need the server shared folders on that server.

What could be causing the server to not listen on tcp/445?

Comment: Do you have have the File Server role enabled and configured?

Comment: Only the Storage Services Role Service is installed under File and Storage Services role. Same as other server that has port 445 listening. SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support is also installed on both.

Comment: Are you able to check if there is a Group Policy active which disables/blocks SMB: `Find the policy named "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level."
Set the value to "Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM & NTLM."`

Comment: **I have a Windows Server 2016 server that is not listening on port 445.** - How did you determine that?

Comment: @Turdie no such policy exists in my domain

Comment: @joeqwerty I used `netstat -nao` on the server

Comment: Have you already rebooted that machine , maybe there is thread hanging or something like that.

Comment: It really sounds like a failed virtual migration. What tool was used, and what other errors and warnings are in the event logs?

Comment: @Turdie yes, multiple times since the issue was discovered.

Comment: I think you need to do a network trace with whireshark or Microsoft network monitor and low level capture the network traffic. and also through analyze the event logs. Otherwise it's a case for Microsoft support i think.

Comment: @GregAskew, we used VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Agent and we did a thin conversion where only the used sized on the drives were cloned. The only error I can find related to the File Server role is Event ID 45 for volmgr "The system could not sucessfully load the crash dump driver."